# phalcon querybuilder total_items always returns 1

Tags: phalcon, query-builder, paginator

I make a query via `createBuilder()` and when executing it (`getQuery()->execute()->toArray()`)
I got **10946** elements. I want to paginate it, so I pass it to:

```
$paginator = new \Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\QueryBuilder(array(
    "builder" => $builder,
    "limit" => $limit,
    "page" => $current_page
));
```

`$limit` is **25** and `$current_page` is **1**, but when doing:

```
$paginator->getPaginate();

$page->total_items;
```

returns **1**.

Is that a bug or am I missing something?

UPD: it seems like when counting items it uses created sql with limit. There is no difference what limit is, limit divided by items per page always equals 1. I might be mistaken.

UPD2: Colleague helped me to figure this out, the bug was in the query phalcon produces: `count()` of the `group by` counts grouped elements. So a workaround looks like:

```
$dataCount = $builder->getQuery()->execute()->count();
$page->next = $page->current + 1;
$page->before = $page->current - 1 > 0 ? $page->current - 1 : 1;
$page->total_items = $dataCount;
$page->total_pages = ceil($dataCount / 100);
$page->last = $page->total_pages;
```

Comment: Any chance of sharing rest of code? From this it is hard to guess. Maybe show how you build query? Are doing joins/group by's?

Comment: Sure, take a look http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/3251/phalcon-querybuilder-total-items-always-returns-1

Comment: What about `$page->items`? Does it have only one item?

Comment: It has `25` which is correct according to the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't much of an answer but this is most likely to be a bug. Great guys at Phalcon took on a massive job that is too big to do it properly in their little free time and things like PHQL, Volt and other big but non-core components do not receive as much attention as we'd like. Also given that most time in the past 6 months was spent on v2 there are nearly 500 bugs about stuff like that and it's counting. I came across considerable issues in ORM, Volt, Validation and Session, which in the end made me stick to other not as cool but more proven solutions. When v2 comes out I'm sure all attention will on the bug list and testing, until then we are mostly on our own. Given that it's all C right now, only a few enthusiast get involved, with v2 this will also change.

If this is the only problem you are hitting, the best approach is to update your query to get the information you need yourself without `getPaginate()`.

Comment: I know that there are a lot of bugs. But http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/3251/phalcon-querybuilder-total-items-always-returns-1 is a week old post and there is no distinct response to it. I hoped for at least an answer like 'it is a bug, we won't fix it at the time, do a workaround', then I would immediately make my workaround a week ago, but instead of it I wait in uncertainty.

Comment: :) remember, no one owes you anything, but I feel the pain man. I was thinking someone will say something here as there are a few guys who know their way around ORM. Next time just assume there is a bug if you checked everything five times and it doesn't work – high probability that it is. Most effort goes to v2 now, if they start spreading around it is unlikely to come out any time soon. Things like that should be maintained, but we have what we have. The core is rather stable and after a year+ of using it there was nothing that could not be worked around, that's just me at least.